# animating a large number of rows/sections in UITableView poor performance

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, animation

we're not talking thousands of rows or anything, although if there was a way to make things scale up that high, I'd love it.

I have a table with 27 sections and 180 rows spread across all sections, and the scenario I'm currently getting stuck in is when I animate things to a model state with only 3 sections and 5 rows, and  (even worse) back again.

I'm batching all the animations with beginUpdates/endUpdates.  My app pretty well locks up for 1-2 seconds on an iphone4 while it figures things out, then the animations start.

I've tried both animating the removal/addition of each row, keeping the sections around (and dropping their row counts to 0 in the removal case), and also animating just the removal/insertions of the sections themselves (when the row count would have dropped to 0).  I would have assumed the latter would give better performance but it didn't change things at all.

Is there anything that can be done on the app end to speed this up?  Right now I have a rather gross bit of code to bail out of the individual animations if there are more than 20 of them, opting to just reloadData instead.

**edit** here's code that exhibits the problem.  The performance of this code is slightly better than the equivalent monotouch code (which is what I was using before), but it's still pretty bad.

```
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface MyTableViewDataSource : NSObject<UITableViewDataSource> {
    int rows;
};

@end

@implementation MyTableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (void)setRowCount:(int)r
{
    rows = r;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return rows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"row %d", indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

@end

@implementation MyTableViewController {
    UIBarButtonItem *populateButtonItem;
};

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        populateButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Populate" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(populateDataSource)];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)populateDataSource
{
    NSMutableArray* new_rows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [((MyTableViewDataSource*)self.tableView.dataSource) setRowCount:200];

    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i ++)
        [new_rows addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:new_rows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.dataSource = [[MyTableViewDataSource alloc] init];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = populateButtonItem;
}

@end
```

Comment: My first guess would be that your table cells are the culprit. Are you using custom cells?

Comment: Can you post some code? Also: are your UITableViewCells opaque?

Comment: What is Instruments indicating is your bottleneck? Are you deleting them en masse with a single deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:... call, or many individual calls? Are you calling reloadData in the middle of animations (you must never do that)?

Comment: I was using a custom cell (not anymore, no change with regular UITableViewCells), cells are opaque.

Comment: the insertion phase is definitely slower than the removal.  gobs slower.  I'm inserting via a single call to insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:  the reloadData I was doing was instead - I computed the differences, and if there were more than 50 (not 20, as stated above), I would reloadData.  otherwise I'd do beginUpdates, insertRowsAtIndexPaths, endUpdates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only makes sense to animate the rows that are visible. Instead of doing the animation for all the rows that you're inserting, consider just animating the insertion of those rows that will be visible.

Also, are you sure that it's the animation that's causing the delay? Do you get the same delay if you pass `UITableViewRowAnimationNone` for the animation, or is it faster? If it's faster, then again, avoid animating those insertions that won't be visible. (You can figure out which rows are currently visible using `-indexPathsForVisibleRows`.) If it's not faster, then the problem is probably not related to the animation at all, but rather the overhead of inserting a few hundred rows all at once. Reloading the entire table as you're now doing is one option; inserting the rows in smaller batches is another.

Finally, it'd be a good idea to profile your app with Instruments while you do the insertion. You'll get a better idea of what the app is doing during that delay, and that's the first step toward eliminating the delay.

Comment: avoiding animating the rows that won't be visible is indeed what I'd like to do.  But it doesn't seem like indexPathsForVisibleRows will give me what I want - the animation is likely going to be filling in the visible area, so the currently visible rows aren't the ones I want to animate... unless indexPathsForVisibleRows is somehow taking into account the rows (and/or sections) I'll be adding/deleting.

Comment: ... that said, switching to UITableViewRowAnimationNone was the ticket.  There's still a very very minor initial pause, barely noticeable. So perhaps it's not so much the number of animations, but perhaps the z-ordering (or clipping?) that UITableView is doing when passing in the various other enum members that was causing the slowdown

Answer (score 1):

You're using `UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic` (Reference: The table view chooses an appropriate animation style for you. (Introduced in iOS 5.0.)), and for some reason, the table view chooses a really bad one, which fades in all rows while expanding them. Changing opacity on 200 `UIViews` while resizing their frame and moving them around HAS to be slow. :)

You can just do this:

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:new_rows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

This will reduce animations to UITableView's very basic animation when inserting rows, which, in my opinion, is absolutely sufficient when inserting that many.

Answer (score 0):

Try to test the same functionality with some hardcoded array of strings and see issue is gone. If issue is still there, it means the problem is with rendering not with data.

For different kind of animation there are some custom controls already made where you can have the faster animation with some nice one liner implementation: [Here](https://github.com/applidium/ADLivelyTableView) have a look.